Laravel 10 problems with Livewire 3.0: can't find livewire.js and all Livewire's components routes
I've problem with my staging deploy configuration.
First, my stack is:

Laravel 10
PHP 8.2
Livewire 3.0

Locally, my software works great but when I deploy it on an Apache stagin machine, I've got some errors.
First, while all Laravel works, livewire.js doesn't load and server return 404.
I'll try to resolve with it, in boot() method, in the appServiceProvider.php file:
Livewire::setScriptRoute(function ($handle) {
            return \Route::get('/vendor/livewire/livewire.js', $handle);
        });

After that, all routes in livewire components, don't work ad I get this error:

The route path was wrong, bu I can see correctly with php artisan route:list command.
Can you help me?
Thanks guys
I've tried all, from server configuration to move Livewire files inside public folder, without any results.
Downgrade livewire version is the last chance for today.
All other laraval's components and plugin seems to work well.

Try a clean install and copy your files in it
